# Javascript - Calling a variable in a literal string with a passed variable name

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way to embed a variable name inside of a literal string without having to substring and build the string back together again?

Example:

```
function(mode) {
    return ${REACT_APP_<mode>_PREFIX_URL};
}
```

Where mode intercepts the literal string ``` (``) ``` as a passed parameter that points the correct variable name to look for.

Here is the Output Example

> Output example: `REACT_APP_ADMIN_PREFIX_URL` for passing in mode=`'ADMIN'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `REACT_APP_ADMIN_PREFIX_URL` is accessible in the global scope you could access it in the same way you'd access a property on any other object like:

```
const val = window[`REACT_APP_${mode}_PREFIX_URL`];
return `REACT_APP_${mode}_PREFIX_URL`;
```

(Assuming here the app is running in the browser, where 'window' is the global object)

Polluting the global scope with config variables can be hard to maintain however, so I'd suggest doing something more like this if possible:

```
const PrefixUrls = {
    ADMIN: 'foobar'
}

function(mode) {
 return PrefixUrls[mode];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right,

```
function myFunc (mode) {
  return obj[`REACT_APP_${mode}_PREFIX_URL`];
}
var obj = {
  REACT_APP_ADMIN_PREFIX_URL : 'Hello'
}

console.log(myFunc('ADMIN'))// Hello
```

should work.

You can also use `eval` although I wouldn't recommend it.

```
var REACT_APP_ADMIN_PREFIX_URL : 'Hello';
function myFunc (mode) {
  return eval(`REACT_APP_${mode}_PREFIX_URL`);
}
```

should also return the same response.

Comment: the 'mode' is another variable name.
Example:
`${REACT_APP_${mode}_PREFIX_URL}`;

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a file with constants, .env with this content:

```
REACT_APP_ADMIN_PREFIX_URL=admin_str
REACT_APP_DEV_PREFIX_URL=dev_str
...
```

You can then have in your (current) file:

```
function(mode) {
  return process.env[`REACT_APP_${mode.toUpperCase()}_PREFIX_URL`};
  // this will be process.env[`REACT_APP_ADMIN_PREFIX_URL`]
  // which is `admin_str`
}
```

Comment: This would work if i exported through a constants file. I have very similar structure, just instead these are held in an .env file for development/production builds, this is why i need to do something like  ${REACT_APP${mode}_PREFIX_URL} inside eachother

Answer (score 0):

```
const CONSTANTS = {
  REACT_APP_ADMIN_PREFIX_URL: '...',
  REACT_APP_OTHER_PREFIX_URL: '...',
}

function(mode) {
    return CONSTANTS['{REACT_APP_'+mode+'_PREFIX_URL'];
}
```

There is **no** way you can do it with variables